# Should the main window be a global variable?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to find a place in my code to create all of the objects that go into my window. As I see it, there are two main types of objects:

- the ones that require the context (`HDC`) such as rectangles, lines, and ellipses
- the ones that require the main window (`HWND`) such as the buttons and other objects created with the `CreateWindow()` function.

The problem is that I don't know where the best place to create all these objects would be. It seems as if they need to be created in different locations, namely the context-dependent ones in `WM_PAINT` and the window-dependent ones in `WM_CREATE` or in `InitInstance()`.

Is this correct, or should I make the window and context global variables that I can access from any function?

Also, when I create a button, I need to keep track of its handle for when there is a `BN_CLICKED` event.

```
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.


    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_SCHEDULERER, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return false;
    }

    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_SCHEDULERER));

    MSG msg;

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
///////////////
//INIT INSTANCE
///////////////
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable

   HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        {
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
            // Parse the menu selections:
            switch (wmId)
            {
            case IDM_ABOUT:
                DialogBox(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_ABOUTBOX), hWnd, About);
                break;
            case IDM_EXIT:
                DestroyWindow(hWnd);
                break;
            case BN_CLICKED:
            {
            }
            default:
                return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
            }
        }
        break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        {
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

            // TODO: Add any drawing code that uses hdc here...



            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        PushButton pb(hWnd, 100, 100, 200, 100, "Button");
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no immediate reason to store the window handle to the application's main window. What would you need it for at a time where you aren't getting access to it?

Comment: "*context-dependent ones in `WM_PAINT`*" - you can create your GDI objects outside of `WM_PAINT` (such as in `WM_CREATE`) and then just use them as needed inside of `WM_PAINT`. You would simply use `SelectObject()` to put them into the `HDC` provided by `BeginPaint()` before drawing with them, and to remove them from the `HDC` when you are done drawing with them.

Comment: Hi ScrumptiousGoat, has this issue been solved?

Answer (score 1):

The `HDC` is generally used in the context of a message that passes it as a parameter, so there's no need to store it.

The `HWND` will definitely be needed in a global context, but it can be either stored directly or as part of a class which has a global instance.

Comment: When do you need the application's top-level window's `HWND`? The only reason I can think of is when creating child windows. Child windows are generally created when handling the `WM_CREATE` message. Coincidentally, the `WM_CREATE` message passes the `HWND` along. So... why would you need to store the application's top-level window's `HWND`?

Comment: @IInspectable I don't remember off the top of my head, but I know I've needed it in the past. Microsoft's MFC and ATL make them accessible at a global level.

Comment: Neither one does. They make them accessible at the object level. Objects in C++ have lifetimes. The lifetime of window objects in MFC and ATL are always shorter than those with static storage duration.

Comment: @IInspectable: While true that the window object doesn't have static lifetime, there's a global object derived from `CWinApp` and that object has a pointer to the window object for the main window.  Mark didn't say the window IS a global, he said it's accessible at a global level, and that is true.

Comment: @ben [AfxGetMainWnd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/application-information-and-management#afxgetmainwnd) is really a concession to the fact, that OLE was a thing. It's true, though, that the application's main window handle is accessible through the `CWinApp`. I have never found a reason to access it, and it feels like this is provided as a convenience to developers that would rather not want to understand the structure of their application.